# nodejs - download file from url without extension

Tags: node.js, download

I have a url of an image from the instagram api: https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ig_messaging_cdn/?asset_id=377709514430912&signature=Abw09J9rNX17PnLujzPUbIyxGjJVcsDEx63SLBE7pS9LmOQr_86OjphnztowTFmdJ-oCTZ1PVoUkmyb9538yVVzuDYOUh9rKhxQDWHTs1Ij8Z8bBXMYS1Zd-GLm6Yff93AVkEAp2gjXKdI7Fe0uropwqe-tBuEfUGj7WzHUxrhD4ADSU-8UyUDeirWoZ_b900mGMO1gJTdmhCptPcH4vIChgI6sG

and wanted to download that file. I tested some scripts like:

```
async function downloadFile (url, targetFile) {  
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const fileWriter = fs
          .createWriteStream("./src/temp/file.png")
          response.pipe(fileWriter)
          .on('finish', () => {
            resolve({})
          })
  
        
      }).on('error', error => {
        reject(error)
        console.log(error)
      })
    })
  }
```

```
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(`./src/temp/file.png`);
        const request = https.get(url , (response)=> {

            response.pipe(file)
            
            file.on("finish", () => {
                file.close();
                console.log("Download Completed");
            });
            
        });
```

but it happens that the file is created but for some reason the content of the image is not displayed. I tested on other image urls and they are all downloaded and displayed. If anyone can help with this, I'd appreciate it!!

Comment: Note, this code is vulnerable to an infinite redirect loop.  Simplest way to avoid that is just create an error after more than a couple redirects.

Comment: Is it possible that you just want to create clicks? The image and the link are somehow suspicious

Comment: actually this image is a print of a part of my screen that I sent on instagram to try to download it